# Android sharing intent on unity with wrong layout

Tags: android, android-intent, unity-game-engine

i'm working on a unity project and i've encountered a strange behaviour when i try to open a native text sharing window in my app, this is the result:

[image]

this is the code i used:

```
    public void shareText(){
    string subject = "sharing";
    string body = "body";

    //execute the below lines if being run on a Android device
    #if UNITY_ANDROID
    //Refernece of AndroidJavaClass class for intent
    AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass ("android.content.Intent");
    //Refernece of AndroidJavaObject class for intent
    AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject ("android.content.Intent");
    //call setAction method of the Intent object created
    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SEND"));
    //set the type of sharing that is happening
    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "text/plain");
    //add data to be passed to the other activity i.e., the data to be sent
    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_SUBJECT"), subject);
    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TEXT"), body);
    //get the current activity
    AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    //start the activity by sending the intent data
    currentActivity.Call ("startActivity", intentObject);
    #endif

}
```

seems like it has a wrong layout but i have no idea where i can define that, tried to find a similar problem online but without success.
any help? thank you so much

Comment: That share functions is absolutely fine. There is something wrong with your Android device. You can test that code on another device to verify what I just said. What Unity version? Android version and what device is this? How are you calling the `shareText()` function?

Comment: Tried on two devices, same result. I'm using unity 5.3, the devices have different android version, lollipop and kitkat. Maybe the problem is in my androidmanifest?

Comment: You don't need to do anything in your Manifest. This worked on my device(4.2) without any modification. Are you doing this on an actual device or emulator?

Comment: like i said i tested on two different actual devices, a moto G lollipop and one samsung 4.2, same result.

Comment: I can't tell what your problem is. Your code is working fine on my device. I suggest you update Unity to 5.4. Maybe that will solve your problem.

Comment: usually i avoid to update unity during the development phase, and i used the same code in other projects made with this version of unity and works fine. Btw thank you so much for your reply

Comment: I understand you. You can update and create a new project to test that function in your question and see if it works. Don't open your current project because it will be updated. If it works, you have to update and stick to that version. If it doesn't, downgrade back to your old version then file a bug report with Unity(Help->Report a Bug...). Maybe they will get it fixed. Anyways, they will probably tell you that it works on their side too.